# Installing Ubuntu server on my PI 3 b+ 21.04 how do I pick a wifi-connrction?

Tags: wifi

My installation is failing I think because I need to choose a wifi connection.  I cannot use an ethernet cable so I need to start-up with the wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu server does not have WiFi support, and is not really designed for it.
It uses `systemd-networkd` for networking.

You may find some instructions on a Ubuntu site using yaml, although the last time I looked they use `Network Manager` for desktop installations. AFAIK it is not possible to install a DM as the Pi3B+ has insufficient memory for a Ubuntu installation.

I have done this using `systemd-networkd` on Raspberry Pi OS and the [method](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117843/8697) should work on Ubuntu, although you will probably need to use *Predictable Network Interface Names* (and may need to install another application such as WPA supplicant).

Comment: I don't intend a web connection with my plan, this is for a local net only.

Comment: I claims it can be put on  pI3b+ But I guess I will have to upgrade to a PI 4 B anyway for other reasons.

Comment: You certainly can install the Server on Pi3+ and I am sure it is possible to install wireless networking. I installed a lightweight DM on top of this on 2Gb Pi4, but from memory there was little left (and frankly it didn't work particularly well). Installing the DM updated networking code to Network Manager.